# Suddenly started getting "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when commenting

Tags: php, laravel

I understand you usually get such an error when you're POST-ing to a GET route but I don't think that is the case. I didn't have any problem with posting comments until now and I am not sure why am I suddenly getting this error.

Maybe I've mistakenly changed something when working on some other feature

View:

```
@auth
                <div class='postComments'>
                    <form method='POST' action=''>
                        <textarea class='commentSection' name='comment'></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="{{ $image->id }}">
                        <button class='Submit' type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                @endauth
```

JS:

```
$('.postComment').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var userId = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
        var imageId = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
        var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlComment,
            data: {
                userId: userId,
                imageId: imageId,
                comment: comment,
                _token: token
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            var commentsCount = response.image.comments;
            $("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
            $('.comments').append('<p>' + response.comment.comment + '</p>');
            $('.commentsCount').html(commentsCount + " Comments");

        })
    });
```

View:

```
Route::post('/comment', 'CommentsController@postComment')->name('comment');
<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlComment = '{{ route('comment') }}';
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function postComment(Request $request){
        $userId = $request['userId'];
        $imageId = $request['imageId'];
        $commentText = $request['comment'];
        $image = Image::find($imageId);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = $userId;
        $comment->image_id = $imageId;
        $comment->comment = $commentText;
        $comment->save();

        $image->updateComments();

        return response()->json(['comment'=>$comment, 'image'=>$image]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this worked before and all of the sudden started to throw `MethodNotAllowedException` then that means that you have another `GET` route on top of this.

So go to the `web.php`
and make sure that this route :

```
Route::post('/comment', 'CommentsController@postComment')->name('comment');
```

is before any similar route:

```
 Route::get('/comment');
```

Comment: I don't have a Route::get('/comment'); or any comment related Get

Comment: then place the post route the very first on the web.php file and try again

Comment: whats the `urlComment``value ?

Comment: Route::post('/comment', 'CommentsController@postComment')->name('comment');

Comment: dude the var value on javascript not the route

Comment: var urlComment = '{{ route('comment') }}'; which is the route to which I want to POST the ajax request. Therefore it should be /comment

Comment: yeah `it should be ` do a `console.log(urlComment)`

Comment: When I console.log(urlComment) I get 2 lines:
http://onyx.space/comment and undefined ( not sure to what it refers )

Comment: add the route manually just to see if its working in ajax call do: `url: '/comment'`

Comment: Getting same error. I haven't changed any of the code used for commenting recently and I'm pretty sure commenting was working last night, no idea what's going on.

Comment: Removed the use of Ajax calls and now commenting is working fine, meaning it's definitely not a back-end problem I guess.

Comment: Well I figured it out, I was changing class names yesterday and forgot to change the class name of my button. It still had class name of Submit when the JavaScript activates on click of .postComment.

Answer (score 0):

Class of button was different from the class in my JavaScript on('click') function.